# PHP if logic returns one result on first run and different results on all subsequent runs

Tags: php, class, function

I'm having a little issue with some php logic in my main index page, that will include certain pages based on the results of some functions, mainly to do with login/logout and the first time a user logs in after registering. The php that manages the includes is below:

UPDATE: (Based on suggestions from @arjan and @bigman I've updated the code as follows. The end result is still the same).

```
<?php
if ($login->checkForRegisterPage()) {
    include("views/pages/home.php");
// are we logged in ?
} elseif ($login->isLoggedIn()) {

    // check whether account is activated
    if (!$login->checkActivated()) {
        include("views/pages/activate.php");

    // check whether user has logged in before
    } elseif ($login->checkFirstLogin()) {
        include("views/pages/build_profile.php");

    // check action in URL and redirect accordingly
    } elseif ($checkaction->checkForBuildProfilePage()) {
        include("views/pages/build_profile.php");
    } elseif ($checkaction->checkForViewProfilePage()) {
        include("views/pages/profile.php");

    // if all else fails, load the dashboard
    } else {
        include("views/pages/dashboard.php");
    }
} else {

    // not logged in, showing the login form
    include("views/pages/home.php");
}
?>
```

The problem is with the two functions $login->checkActivated(); and $login->checkFirstLogin(); included below:

```
public function checkFirstLogin() {
  $checkfirstlogin = $this->db->query("SELECT first_login FROM users WHERE first_login = 'Y' AND user_name = '".$this->user_name."';");

  if($checkfirstlogin->num_rows == 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}


public function checkActivated() {
  $checkactivated = $this->db->query("SELECT activated FROM users WHERE activated = 'N' AND user_name = '".$this->user_name."';");

  if($checkactivated->num_rows == 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

When the user first logs in, these functions return the correct result and I receive the page that I want. However, after login, I can still click and travel to other links on the page e.g. `checkForViewProfilePage();` looks for view=profile in the URL. The thing is in order for the logic to reach the point where it even checks for that, it would have had to get past the two functions `checkActivate();` and `checkFirstLogin();`, which it shouldn't be able to do while those criteria are met, but it still can. I hope I'm making sense. Can anyone see an error?

Obviously my login form calls the Login class which the awkward functions are stored in, and so this would be loaded on login, but the class is included in the same way here so I'm not sure why the functions don't appear to be firing.

Comment: The reason for needing this is that at the moment the activation form that is included at views/pages/activate.php id loaded immediately after login, but cannot redirect back to itself when the user enters a wrong activation code, and instead loads views/pages/dashboard.php as if the account were activated and has logged in before, neither of which are true.

Comment: @bigman I'm not sure whether to take that as a compliment or a slight at my amateurish coding.

Comment: don't take it as a slight, take it as constructive criticism.  Work the code out in a more psuedo manner and try and come up with a cleaner solution, that's usually when the answer will come to you.

Comment: Please take the time to correctly indent your code when posting questions. Nobody enjoys reading code that scrolls off the right side of the page because it's massively over-indented.

Comment: @bigman constructive criticism is always welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was higher up in the Login class - in Login db connections are only created when a session_start() is fired, i.e. on first login. Created a new class with db connection launched with each function and everything worked as it was.

Thanks to @arjan and @bigman for the formatting tips r.e. nesting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use elseif to stop the nesting from going deeper. 
also, why call every function twice? Only once in the if should be enough.

Comment: That was an attempt to force it to fire as it didnt appear to be doing so, I forgot to remove it before posting. I'll edit my original post.